# How to stop redirect to default website when IP address is entered in the address bar of the browser?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have multiple websites hosted on our server. When someone types the IP address in the address bar of the Browser It redirects to one of the websites hosted on the server. Is there any way by which I can set the default website which is opened when some one types the IP address. Same IP address is being shared by multiple websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 IP address can only bind to 1 IIS Entry.  So what you need to do is to pick the IIS entry you want, go the "Binding" section and bind your IP as the binding header.

ex: If your IP is 1.1.1.1 , then in binding header, you put 1.1.1.1,  in IP address, you also choose 1.1.1.1.

After you setup this binding, you can browse to 1.1.1.1 and it'll open your site.

Remember to make sure all other sites doesn't have this binding. Otherwise, it'll have an conflict.

Comment: For this I had to go the properties of the wesite that I wanted to set as the Default website for IP address and in the Advanced Section for IP Address add a new entry with empty host header. Also made sure that no other website had empty host header value.

Comment: You're absolutely right, all other sites has to have something for host header value.  Empty means wildcard and it'll overwrite other iis entries.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is *leave off* the IP address and host name entries, and provided you have only a single website matching that, that site will become the 'default', while your other sites will have specific host name(s) they respond to.

Comment: Can you please tell the steps to do this? I am new to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you may have to add a specific host in the `C:\\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, giving IP address and its corresponding address, this definitely works from logging into the website where it is hosted, i.e on the hosting server.

For logging from different IP machines, try the same logic - in this case make sure that the gateway is same for LAN.

Let's see what happens in this case ??